# Wanted: C# programming library for mathematics

Tags: c#, .net, math, .net-3.5, interpolation

What I need is: plots creation, stuff for interpolation, stuff for counting such things as

[image]

and

[image]

where L(x) is an interpolation built  from some data (points) generated from original known function f(x). meaning we know original function. we have a range (-a, a) - known. We need library to help us calculate data points in range. we need to calculate L(x) a polinom using that data in that range.

I need this library to be free and opensource

Comment: Maybe you can find something here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#.NET_Framework_Languages_C.23.2C_F.23_and_VB.NET

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommended math library for C#/.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387430/recommended-math-library-for-c-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For plot creation, you may want excel interop (why not ?), or [ILNumerics.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ILNumerics.Net).

But I don't understand the other requirements. You want to measure interpolation errors (in the max and L1 norm) from a function you don't know ? This is not a programming question, it is a math question.

I suggest you look at interpolation libraries (Math.NET contains one for instance, but many others also do) and see if they provide such things as "error estimation".

Otherwise, what you need is a math book which will explain you the assumptions on `f` that you need to estimate the interpolation error. It depends on what you know about the regularity of `f` and the interpolation method.

**Edit, regarding additional information provided:** There are closed form formulas for interpolation errors ([here as a starting point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Interpolation_error)). But any numerical integration routine (which Math.NET *does not* provide) will get what you want. Have a look at libraries other people pointed out, [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#.NET_Framework_Languages_C.23.2C_F.23_and_VB.NET) will get you started.

Since you seem to have regular functions (since you do polynomial interpolation), I'd go with simple [Romberg integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romberg's_method), which is quite simple to implement in case you don't find a library that suits your need (I doubt it). Have a look at Numerical Recipes, 3rd edition for sample code.

Comment: Update: Math.NET Numerics does supports basic numerical integration (double exponential); Math.NET Iridium (predecessor) does not.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps [Math.NET](http://www.mathdotnet.com/) can help you.

Comment: Math.NET doesn't provide anything to compute integrals numerically.

Comment: Found this in the docs: "numerical function integration (quadrature) routines" - quadrature is a form of numerical integration.  Maybe you should read up on it.

Comment: I read http://www.mathdotnet.com/doc/IridiumFeatures.ashx and didn't find quadrature methods inside. Perhaps I should reconsider Math.NET if it provides enough stuff not documented there.

Comment: @Alexandre C. - I didn't look in the code itself or exercise their capabilities.  I'm going on published docs, so if it's vaporware I wouldn't know it.  I think it deserves a deeper dive.

Comment: Update: Math.NET Numerics supports numerical integration, Math.NET Iridium (predecessor) does not.

Answer (score 2):

Check this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387430/recommended-math-library-for-c-net, in particular several people think that MathDotNet is nice.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NETLink/tutorial/CallingNETFromMathematica.html)?

Comment: It is not free or open source. It is awesome, but that wasn't one of the requirements.

Comment: An open source and free library was explicitly asked for.

Comment: It's also not C#.  Octave is free, open source, and awesome (it's a MatLab clone) and would do everything requested, but it still is not C#.

Answer (score 1):

[Math.NET](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) and [ILNumerics.Net](http://ilnumerics.net/) are both open source and will both solve your equations.